# Branding for the Team Site

Tags: team-sites

I have a sharepoint solution which comprises of Branding solution with all necessary features, styles and Master page. We are using a customised Master page. I would like to use the same Master all over site (including in Team site and other subsites). In this way, I would like to have the same branding all over the website. Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using feature stapling? Feature stapling is designed to activate a feature when a new site is created. Whether it activates can be setup to determine the site template id of the new site. In your case you would simply make sure to activate the stapling when you are creating a site of the templates you require. Once you have this you can simply add your masterpage to your feature and then use a feature event receiver to set the new site's masterpage to your custom one.

Here is an example of someone walking through the steps required:

http://www.olavaukan.com/tag/feature-stapling/